# AWK to resolve CSV values

Tags: awk

I have two CSV files.  One is a dictionary, and the other is a file i want to modify.   The dictionary has 3 columns:

```
DEPT_CODE,DEPT,DEPT_NAME
500,Billing,Billing Department
300,Accounting,Accounting Department
...
```

The input file has 7 columns:

```
TF,DOC,SECTION,XOFFSET,HEADING,YOFFSET,DEPT_CODE
TRUE,JOURNAL,Header Section,12345,Heading 1,55152,500
FALSE,BINDER,Body Section,23456,Heading 2,66425,300
...
```

I want to use AWK to substitute the 7th column of the input file with the 2nd column of the dictionary file when Column 7 of the input file and Column 1 of the dictionary file match.

For example:

```
TRUE,JOURNAL,Header Section,12345,Heading 1,55152,Billing
FALSE,BINDER,Body Section,23456,Heading 2,66425,Accounting
...
```

I'm using the following and not getting any results.  What am I doing wrong?

```
awk -F',|, ' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR{$7=a[$7];print}' OFS=',' "$dictionary.csv" "$input.csv"
```

Comment: I used | delimiters in my question context, but my real data has , delimiters.

Comment: Will the dictionary file have more than one line?

Comment: What about the headers?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} $7=a[$7]' dict file

Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Billing
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Accounting
```

Answer (score 0):

Phew!

Given your example data with a header:

```
$ cat /tmp/f1.txt
DEPT_CODE,DEPT,DEPT_NAME
500,Billing,Billing Department
300,Accounting,Accounting Department
$ cat /tmp/f2.txt
TF,DOC,SECTION,XOFFSET,HEADING,YOFFSET,DEPT_CODE
TRUE,JOURNAL,Header Section,12345,Heading 1,55152,500
FALSE,BINDER,Body Section,23456,Heading 2,66425,300
```

You can do:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} FNR<2 {next} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} {$7=a[$7]; print}'  /tmp/f1.txt /tmp/f2.txt
TRUE,JOURNAL,Header Section,12345,Heading 1,55152,Billing
FALSE,BINDER,Body Section,23456,Heading 2,66425,Accounting
```

Comment: really no deception here.  basically need to lookup the value of the 7th column.

Comment: When i run either of these, i just get: Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,

Comment: @didjit no one thinks you're trying to deceive us but MAYBE there's something in your columns 1->6 that matters to the solution but which you haven't recognized as important. That's why it's important for you to post some truly representative data instead of just making up some single-word space-fillers across all fields on all lines. The fact that this solution isn't working for you indicates there probably IS something relevant about your real data that you haven't shown us yet.

Comment: There is nothing in the fields whose sample values you have now chosen to share with us that would cause the problem you are having so the problem is probably in the remaining fields whose values you are still for some reason refusing to show us examples of, e.g. `Heading 1`. I suspect by now most people have lost interest in this question but it MAY not be too late for you to try one more time to edit your question to include the info we'd need to help you. Good luck!